# Flash AS3 game loop : functions on separate frames

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, game-loop

I want to use this to keep my functions on the current frame

```
function gameloop(e:Event) {
    if(currentFrame > 1){
        return;
    }
}
```

But I also need to have functions in the game loop separate from frame 1, I just can't do that or else I get the error

```
duplicate function definition
```

I need help, and any is appreciated

Comment: Look into using a document class with your game.  Right now it's difficult to understand your question, my guess would be that you don't understand the proper scope of how methods and vars exist in programming languages.   If you can, try and better explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Like @LDMS said. Or code on a single frame, and if you need frames then create a **game** movieclip. And all call are made outside it - `game.gotoAndStop(2);`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you aren't using OOP, and that is alright. Your problem is that you're remaking functions in subsequent keyframes.  If you want to avoid using classes in AS3, the best way is to have a central layer with a single keyframe that spans the entirety of your movie.  You put all your global variables and function on there.  Then you can access them throughout the entire movie.  You are getting a 'duplicate function definition' error because you are rewriting a function rather than extending its scope within the timeline.